# Searching for words in list

Tags: python, docx

I am trying to make this script find words from the list `to_remove` in my docs file and if found color them.

Everything works fine but it found only one word from list. It seems like the loop does not work after finding this one word. Is there any mistakes in  my script? Thanks.

```py
import docx
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from docx.shared import RGBColor

def replace_words(doc_name, words_dict, to_remove):

    doc = docx.Document(doc_name)
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        for find_text, replace_text in words_dict.items():
            para.text = para.text.replace(find_text, replace_text)
        for run in para.runs:
            for to_remove_text in to_remove:
                if to_remove_text in run.text:
                    idx = run.text.find(to_remove_text)
                    if idx > 0:
                        para.add_run(run.text[:idx])
                    new_run = para.add_run(to_remove_text)
                    new_run.font.bold = True
                    new_run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
                    if idx + len(to_remove_text) < len(run.text):
                        para.add_run(run.text[idx + len(to_remove_text):])
                    run._element.clear_content()

    new_doc_name = os.path.splitext(doc_name)[0] + "_replaced" + os.path.splitext(doc_name)[1]
    doc.save(new_doc_name)

def browse_file():

    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                           filetypes=(("Word documents", "*.docx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    return file_path


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = browse_file()

if file_path:
    words_dict = {"eco-friendly": "sustainable", "nature-friendly": "natural", "ecological": "planet friendly",
                  "high quality": "excellent", "top quality": "outstanding", "premium quality": "superb",
                  "suitable for": "compatible for", "guarantee": "commitment","Eco-friendly": "Sustainable",
                  "Nature-friendly": "Natural", "Ecological": "Planet friendly",
                  "High quality": "Excellent", "Top quality": "Outstanding", "Premium quality": "Superb",
                  "Suitable for": "Compatible for", "Guarantee": "Commitment"}

    # words_dict = {key.lower(): value for key, value in words_dict.items()}

    to_remove = ["free shipping", "low price", "cheap", "buy now", "top rater", "bestseller","bestseller!"
                 "satisfaction guaranteed", "discount", "special promotion", "on sale", "top selling","Free shipping",
                 "Low price", "Cheap", "Buy now", "Top rater", "Bestseller","Bestseller!"
                 "Satisfaction guaranteed", "Discount", "Special promotion", "On sale", "Top selling"]
    # remove_list = [word.lower() for word in to_remove]

    replace_words(file_path, words_dict, to_remove)

    print("Words replaced successfully. New document created.")

else:
    print("No file selected.")
```

I cannot find solution for this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your program and see what goes wrong where?

Comment: Yes, everything works well, there is no bugs and new file looks fine

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, try looking through the [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) style guide for python.